# How to start new facebook web application

Tags: c#, facebook

I made in the past desktop application for facebook (in c# winform), 
Now I have idea for another application, I already did a prototype for it,
And I want to write it on facebook web application

- What are the main differences in building desktop facebook application to web facebook application?
- Do you have any suggestion how should I start the web application?
- How do you manage database in web application? (can I use entity framework or there is anything else that is more appropriate/simple for it)
- Do you have any link to simple facebook web application that you can share?

I will write it with C#, so please be focus on that language

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably base it around the Facebook JavaScript SDK, at least that's what the Docs recommend these days. A really simple "Hello User" type app (really just a simple webpage) could look something like this:

```
<html><body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
   appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
   status : true, // check login status
   cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    FB.api('/me', function(api_response) {
      document.getElementById("usr-name").innerHTML=api_response.name;
      document.getElementById("app-content").style.display="block";
    });
  }
  else {
    alert("not logged in!") ;
  }
});
</script>
<div id="app-content" style="display:none">
Hello <span id="usr-name"></span>!
</div>
</body></html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But how can I combine c# with it?

Comment: Well, all the facebook API calls are done client-side with plain JavaScript, so if you're making an ASP.NET web app or something any logic in your app relating to facebook directly would need to be passed back to your server by the client script, e.g. using HTTP POST.